# (Discrete) Random variables are dependent if they the same preimage for some element

Tags: random-variables, definition, independence

Can two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ be independent of eachother, if there exist elements $x_0$ and $y_0$ such that $\{X=x_0\}$ and $\{Y=y_0\}$ are the same set (that has nonzero and nonunit probability)?

I'm wrestling with the definition of independence of random variables currently and it seems to me that two such random variables cannot be independent, because to be independent for *all* $x$ and $y$  the sets $\{X=x\}$ and $\{Y=y\}$ have two be independent (in the sense of independent events). But identical sets $A$ cannot be independent, since $P(A\cap A)=P(A) \neq P(A)\cdot P(A)$ (unless the have probability $0$  or $1$ which I both excluded).

Comment: Clearly they are dependent, since $X = x_0$ iff $Y = y_0$. Informally, $X$ and $Y$ are independent iff knowing the value of $X$ gives you no extra information about the probability that $Y$ takes a given value.

Comment: The condition that $P[x =x_0] \neq 0, 1$ is an important detail, however.

Comment: @Vik78 How would you interpret this details informally?

Comment: I would use the definition of independence. Suppose $X, Y$ are independent. Then by definition, $P[X=x_0 \cap Y=y_0] = P[X=x_0]*P[Y=y_0]$. But if the event $X = x_0$ is equivalent to $Y = y_0$, then $\{X=x_0\} \cap \{Y = y_0 \} = \{X = x_0\}$, and $P[X=x_0 \cap Y=y_0] = P[X = x_0]$. This is a contradiction if $P[X = x_0] = P[Y=y_0]\neq 0, 1$.